# Unable to access to GMail with firefox

Tags: firefox, gmail, https

I'm  unable to access to gmail using firefox 7.0.1 on Windows7

I'm able to access to my GMail account with another browser.

I verified the encryption

`Tools -> Options -> Advanced`

And both check boxes `Use SSL 3.0` and `Use TLS 1.0` are checked.

I tried to type the address directly into the address bar.

It seems that other https sites are slower... I didn't mesure it though.

What is going on ?

---

**EDIT**

It still doesn't work and I've noticed that `ocsp.thawte.com` is accessed by the browser when I access to gmail with firefox.

Comment: 1. can you access Firefox with a different browser?  2. what is your error message (if any). 3. what is the exact URL you're trying to access?

Comment: @wizlog 1) ??? 2) `The connection to mail.google.com was interrupted while the page was loading.` 3) I've tried `gmail.com`,  `https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#inbox`, `https://gmail.com`

Comment: 1) is an important question, it lets us know if the issue is with the broser or something external to it - like your machine, local connection or internet connection

Comment: @Paul I don't understand the question. Can I access Firefox with a different browser ??? I can access `GMail` with another browser, like I wrote in the question. I don't know how `to access Firefox`.

Comment: Oh! And Yes and I can access GMail with Firefox with another PC on my network.

Comment: Ooops, sorry I misread it and so did wizlog I reckon.  Ok, can you try starting firefox in safemode in case it is an issue with extensions or a corrupt profile?  You should have an option in your Start menu, otherwise, you just start firefox with --safe-mode after firefox.exe

Comment: @Paul Sorry, I lent my laptop and I get it back. I've tried --safe-mode, still the same issue. It's weird because every account on this computer has not access to GMail. I'm looking for security settings.

Comment: Yeah, check if your AV is preventing access (some transparently proxy web connections) it is worth checking c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and make sure there are no cgmail or mail.google.com entries in there, which would suggest foul play.

Comment: @LucM have you tried to clear cache and other private data?

Comment: @Eir, yes I'have done that. I re-installed it after an uninstallion.